# tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for ....node1, not localhost"

Tags: kubernetes

I want to configure Jenkins job to deploy remotely helm chart. I tried to regenerate new certificate using on control plane:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt |grep DNS
```

Output:

```
DNS:k8s1, DNS:kubernetes, DNS:kubernetes.default, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, IP Address:10.96.0.1, IP Address:192.168.xx, IP Address :192.168.xx, IP Address:192.168.xx, IP Address:192.168.xx, IP Address:127.0.0.1
```

Delete the old apiserver certificate

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.* -f
```

Generate the required apiserver certificate

```
kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.xx --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 192.168.xx --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 192.168.xx --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 192.168. xx --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 127.0.0.1 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans <jenkins_server_ip> --apiserver-cert-extra-sans <node1_ip> --apiserver-cert-extra-sans <node2_ip>
```

Now I can deploy successfully helm chart but I get error on the second work node:

```
Sep 25 22:11:33 node2 kubelet[9073]: I0925 22:11:33.776574    9073 status_manager.go:853] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID="82608ce3-08b9-434a-81a9-6d0d15078917" pod="kube-system/calico-kube-controllers-5fb8ccdcd6-n9dh8" err="Get \"https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/calico-kube-controllers-5fb8ccdcd6-n9dh8\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, node1, not localhost"
Sep 25 22:11:33 node2 kubelet[9073]: I0925 22:11:33.783688    9073 status_manager.go:853] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID="7eaeeea8-a6f9-4cb9-a86d-7e07cbfb576c" pod="kube-system/nodelocaldns-8zpw8" err="Get \"https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/nodelocaldns-8zpw8\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, node1, not localhost"
```

As you can see work node is not ready:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME    STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
node1   Ready      control-plane   33h   v1.28.2
node2   NotReady   <none>          33h   v1.28.2
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?